# Element is not on focus and can not be clicked

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to delete a value from input field and to save the changes. I have problem with clicking Save button. That is something that works in all other tests, only here doesn't work. May be because the form is long and I need to scroll till element is viewable. I have searched and tried most of the suggestions here, but nothing works. That is my code:

```
//deleting input field
    WebElement sesstimeout = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    sesstimeout.clear();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
//scroll until element is viewable and click save
    WebElement savebutton= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='orgSettingsContainer']/div/div/form/div[9]/button"));

    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", savebutton);

    savebutton.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

I want to clear that field:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmtGF.png)

And to save changes with this button, which is not visible without scroll down:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTxOx.png)

Comment: Do you have some errors?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ , your exact _Manual Step_ 
 and the _error_ you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks. I don,t see any errors with that code, but the deletion of the field is not saved.
I can see how field is cleared , than the test is finished with success , but when I open the form I see the old data in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use Action class:

```
Actions a=new Actions(driver);
action.dragAndDropBy("scroll bar path", int xOffset, int yOffset).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code to Scroll Down :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                                js.executeScript("scroll(0, 1000);");
```